# MATLAB:Why the result of comparing the same white image gives NaN?

Tags: matlab

Salam alikum:
I want to create an OCR system that is based on template matching.
So, I`ll input an image that contains a text such as 'Hello World', then my algorithm results in the Hello World as a text.
I have created a database of all the chars+the white space as images.
I have successfully extracted all the characters except the white space between the two words.
When trying to compare the image that represent the space in my database by the white space in the image that contains the text using the ***corr2*** MATLAB function, it always gives **NaN**.

> Even when comparing the same white image by it self it results NaN.

Help me in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the definition of corr, your are dividing by zero by zero if all elements are equal to the mean.

Comment: Ok, but how to perform the comparsion between the same all white pixels images?

Comment: Usually for regions that have zero variance (a.k.a a region full of white), there is never any correlation with your template.  As such, as Daniel stated with the 0/0 error, when you detect this situation, assign a correlation score of 0.  Also, take a look at the `normxcorr2` command. It creates a correlation map between a template and a match image and you can search that map for the greatest correlation location, thus corresponding to where your template may lie.